# Scroll down to special div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple jQuery plugin that will scroll page down until it reaches special div like a `#stopscroll`. I got a simple jQuery plugin to stop scroll on special size:

```
 $(window).scroll(checkscroll);  


      function checkscroll(){
          var top = $(window).scrollTop();
          if(top > 300){
            $('#share_box').fadeOut('slow');
          }else{
            $('#share_box').fadeIn('slow');
          }
      }

   checkscroll();
```

How do I make it scroll to a special div instead of scrolling a specified size? I want it to stop scrolling when div `#sharebox` reach `#stopscroll`.

Comment: not getting your english, maybe create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correct but I think I had the same problem a while back. I fixed it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /** HIDE MENU **/
    $(".menu").css("margin-top", "-88px");
    var mustSlideDown = true;
    var mustSlideUp = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var verschil = ($(window).scrollTop() / 5);

        if (verschil > 40 && mustSlideDown)  {

            $('.menu').animate({'margin-top': '0px' }, {duration: 500, queue: false});
            mustSlideDown = false;
            mustSlideUp = true;
        }
        else if (verschil < 40 && mustSlideUp) {

            $('.menu').animate({'margin-top': '-88px' }, {duration: 500, queue: false});
            mustSlideUp = false;
            mustSlideDown = true;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: that i wanna to do to scroll down until #share_box reach div #stopscroll and then stop scroll. thanks for answering and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get much of your English, but maybe you are looking for this-

```
Window.location='#scollDiv';
```